# Line chart visualization to Sunburst

Tags: python-3.x, plotly, plotly-python, plotly-express

I have a dataframe which looks like this:

```
id         date          API_changes    count    content

134     2019-01-01           2           NaN      Nan
134     2019-02-05          34           12       API deleted
134     2019-02-12          18            8       Deprecation
134     2019-03-10          56           29       Segmentation Error
134     2019-05-12          75           40       Path deleted
134     2019-07-01          25           10       Type required
134     2019-10-09          137          55       API deprecated
134     2019-12-31          32           18       Media type removed
134     2020-01-03          150          99       Required param missing
```

I want to visualize this data in the form of a sunburst, or any chart which can capture the proportion of `count` in `API_changes`. `count` specifies the number of breaking changes out of the `API_changes` for every `commit_date`.

I earlier visualized this in the form of a scatter plot with traces(with `date` on x axis, `API_changes` on y axis, `color` as `content` column, and same for `symbol` as well), but that does not serve the purpose as I cannot see visually over the dates, how the changes differ in size

One option would be stacked-bar chart, but I was thinking are there more unique charts(preferably a sunburst) for this type of analysis?

Comment: This code works, the previous code seemed to return an error I didn't quite understand, thank you so much!

Comment: @BrieMerryWeather So basically the code I had before, minus the "groupedby"?

Comment: Yes it was quite helpful, thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try and use [Plotly Express](https://plotly.com/python/plotly-express/), which has direct support for [Sunburst graph](https://plotly.com/python/sunburst-charts/).

Assuming a `data.csv` with:

```
id,date,API_changes,count,content
134,2019-01-01,2,,NaN
134,2019-02-05,34,12,API deleted
134,2019-02-12,18,8,Deprecation
134,2019-03-10,56,29,Segmentation Error
134,2019-05-12,75,40,Path deleted
134,2019-07-01,25,10,Type required
134,2019-10-09,137,55,API deprecated
134,2019-12-31,32,18,Media type removed
134,2020-01-03,150,99,Required param missing
```

You can read the CSV file into a DataFrame:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
```

And create the Sunburst graph:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df['date'] = df['date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

fig = px.sunburst(
    df,
    path=['date', 'content'],
    values='count',
    color='API_changes',
    color_continuous_scale='viridis',
    title='API Changes Sunburst Chart',
    height=600,
)

fig.show()
```